# Set values to 0 if rownames contains specific words in R

Tags: r, if-statement, r-rownames

Consider the following data.frame in R:

```
df <- data.frame(Agriculture = c(2,7,2),
                 Fishery     = c(1,4,7),
                 Industry    = c(5,7,3))

rownames(df) <- t(colnames(df))
```

If the rownames is "Fishery" or "Industry", I want to set the row values to 0. I could easily do it like this:

```
df[2:3,1:3] <- 0
```

However, in my case I have a big data.frame where this approach is not the best. Instead I want to define a character vector for row names matching, like this:

```
list_of_industries <- c("Fishery", "Industry")
```

And thereafter, this should be used to set the values to 0 in my `df`. But not sure how I should do that. How to do that in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `which()` together with `%in%` to find out which row has the target rownames.

### My original answer

```
df[which(rownames(df) %in% list_of_industries), ] <- 0
```

### Updated answer credit to @Ritchie Sacramento

In the comment under this answer, @Ritchie Sacramento pointed out we can directly use the vector to match rownames.

```
df[list_of_industries, ] <- 0
```

### Output

The two codes above generate the same output.

```
            Agriculture Fishery Industry
Agriculture           2       1        5
Fishery               0       0        0
Industry              0       0        0
```